# Would anyone help these various latency?

Tags: audio

This may not be suitable for electrical engineering stackexchange. The problem may not be in hardware at all.

Basically I have omni 10 speakers. If I use bluetooth to connect to the speaker there is 1 second sound latency.

If I use a short 3.5 mm cable I have 400 ms latency. If I uses 3 m 3.5 mm cable I got 1000 ms latency. So there has to be some electrical engineering something here.

If I uses my cellphone to use bluetooth I got 1000 ms latency.

Here is the thing. My headphones have no latency.

Either from computer or from my cellphone there is no latency at all.

Maybe because my LBS 730 support aptx codec. However my red mi note 3 doesn't support aptx codec.

I then uses google chromecast audio. That uses wifi, by the way. The latency is 3500 ms.

WIFI. How come wifi has more latency than bluetooth? Is it because the router is outside the room? I wonder if I uses google chromecast with a wifi repeater in the room that my computer can connect to straight. Will I have latency?

Again. Electrical engineering may not be the issue. Maybe it's just software, codec.

But I would appreciate input from electrical engineering on why I have all these latency.

Comment: There is no specific question here, and the variety of questions vaguely alluded to are entirely unanswerable without exact specification of the nature of the data carried by the various transports and the details of the encoders and decoders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is codec software, and maybe a few measurement errors. Check your processes and equipment.

Assuming your 3.5mm cables are analog audio, then there would not be the 600 millisecond difference in latency. At most, the difference would be 11 nanoseconds.

But all digital audio has some latency, and codecs vary widely. Some devices are all in hardware, others all in software, and most are in between. Also, most streaming software buffer the audio data, to allow short disruptions in transmissions. I stream using VLC, using a 1 second buffer, giving over a second of latency.